# Eclipseの自動的にビルドについて

Tags: java, eclipse

どうも、こんにちは
Eclipseでjava開発の勉強をしている人です。

保存するたびにコンパイルされるのは遅いので、Eclipseで「自動的にビルド」のチェックを外してみました。

そしたら、tomcatでデバッグする時に古い*.jarでデバッグをするようになってしまいました。
EclipseさんにはVisualStudioみたいにデバッグボタンがクリックされると同時に、自動的にビルドを開始してほしいのです。

デバッグを開始すると同時にコンパイルしてくれるようにできませんか？

Answer (score 2):

ウィンドウメニューの設定から、
「実行／デバッグ」＞「起動」の中にある一般オプションの、

「起動時に（必要に応じて）ビルド」

がたしかそのような設定ではなかったかと思います。

[image: 起動設定]

Comment: flied onion さん 回答ありがとうございました。

教えて頂いた設定を行ったのですが、残念ながらファイルを修正してもtomcatに修正内容が反映されていないことがありました。

tomcat終了 --> ファイルの修正 --> tomcat起動(デバッグボタン) --> ブラウザに変更内容が表示されない。

ブラウザのキャッシュはOFFにしているので、tomcat側の問題なのかなと思います。やはり、tomcat + eclipseだけでは力不足なのでしょうか？

Comment: tomcatの問題ではなく、Eclipseの設定で、ファイル保管と同時にビルドしてないことが原因だと思われます。なので手動で「プロジェクトのビルド」を行ってから、Tomcatのデバッグ起動をされるべきではないかと。（一発ではできません）